# ROS wrapper for Segway RMP440 Omni

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is anyone developing a ROS wrapper for Segway RMP440 Omni or has already developed it?
http://rmp.segway.com/about-segway-robotics/segway-rmp400-omni/

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58038/ros-wrapper-for-segway-rmp440-omni/) by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 184 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume the RMP440 Omni uses the new protocol used by the RMP440 (http://rmp.segway.com/about-segway-robotics/segway-rmp440-le-and-se/).  If so William's driver won't work on it.  We have a student in our group currently working on a wrapper for the new protocol.  I'm not sure of the status, but I'll check on it and try to post shortly.

---

Originally posted by [david.hodo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1902/david.hodo/) with karma: 395 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) on 2013-03-14**:
@david.hodo I think you're right. The RMP400 Omni is a new model that came out last year. Look forward to hearing the student's progress. Thanks!

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-14**:
I know someone who contacted me about supporting the x440 (similar protocol), but when I declined he said that he implemented his own. I have pointed him to this question, so hopefully he can chime in later.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it is a 400 Omni, it should work with the old protocol and Willam's lib[1] should be the starting point. Probably it needs to be adapted to the nonholonomic kinematics.

If it is a **440** Omni, it uses the new API.

Best Georg

EDIT:
[1] https://github.com/segwayrmp/

---

Originally posted by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) with karma: 328 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) on 2013-03-15**:
Oops made a mistake. It's the 440 Omni. (The Segway site is confusing.)

**Comment by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on 2013-03-17**:
I will try to get approval by my company for releasing my lib and ros node as open source. I do not yet support the 3D motion commands for the omni, but this should be a minor task.

**Comment by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) on 2013-03-18**:
@Georg that'd really awesome! Please let me know. I have no use for 3D motion at least in the near future. Thanks!

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2014-11-13**:
Hello @George,
Just following up by asking if any libraries have been released?
Thanks